# Can you cast a vector<int64> to a vector<uint8>

Tags: c++

In C++ what is the correct way to cast a vector of `int64_t` to `uint8_t`?

I understand I could to this:

```
std::vector<int64_t> int64Vec;
std::vector<uint8_t> uint8Vec(int64Vec.begin(), int64Vec.end());
```

But I think creates an unnecessary copy. Is it possible to cast the vector?

The reason why is that `uint8vec` is passed to a function which expects a `uint8_t` vector.

Comment: You can't. How could you? Think about the memory layout of both vectors.

Comment: Did you also check if it's safe? Why is it initially 64bit when it contains only 8bit values? If they contain 64bit values, casting it to 8bit will give you 'fun' results...

Comment: Can you tell us more about your use case? What lead you to the conclusion that you need to do this?

Comment: Are you allowed to make that function more generic?

Comment: Are you trying to `reinterpret` the int64's as uint8's? If so, and you can't change the interfaces to some custom datatype that would support looking at the data both as bytes and ints, then it's probably impossible without changing the guts of std::vector (i.e. creating a new vector inplace from the backing store of another that has incompatible type). You should just copy the data, unless you have performance metrics that say this is critical.

Comment: This question is still open. Doesn't the answer you've gotten answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to cast the vector?

No.

> The reason why is that uint8vec is passed to a function which expects a uint8_t vector.

What should be fixed is that function. If the function would accept iterators instead (that when dereferenced yield a type that can be converted to `uint8_t`) there would be no issue:

```
template <typename IT>
void function( IT begin, IT end);
```

Perhaps add sanity checks for the type `IT` to get readable error messages in case `IT` does not dereference to a type that can be converted to `uint8_t`.